# How to exit a function where no regex matches

Tags: swift, regex

Attempting to create a function that uses regex matches to return an array of NSRange values to use with a UITextView to allow the user to click through the matched words using animation.

I assume the solution is to break out of the function if there is no regex match.  I cannot figure out how to do this where the function requires a NSRange value.

Moreover, when there is no match, the regex function **matches** does not return nil.  Instead, it automatically returns an empty array which appears to make the guard statement useless.

Here is the function:

```
func rangeOfSearchText(searchString: String, UIText: String) -> [NSRange] {

var matches:[NSTextCheckingResult]?

let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: searchString, options: .caseInsensitive)

matches = regex.matches(in: UIText, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: UIText.count))

guard let find = matches else {

    //return need to find a way to break out of function if nil without returning an NSRange object...

}

var rangeArray:[NSRange] = []

for match in find {

    rangeArray.append(match.range(at: 0))

    }

return rangeArray

}

let sString = "z"

let longString = "I need a solution."

let test = rangeOfSearchText(searchString: sString, UIText: longString)
```

The above returns an empty array.

Comment: is there a reason why you do not want to return an empty array? since it is logical that the result array is an empty one should no match occur. you can then handle it outside of this function by checking if test.count is 0

Comment: Funny, that is what I have been working on doing.  Sometimes the simple solutions are overlooked.

Comment: so I guess if you dont mind an empty array then you can break out of the function in the guard statement by returning []

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. As per your suggestion, it is pretty easy to return the empty array and test.count for 0.  I don't code for a living so I often get wrapped around the axle on simple things.

Comment: no problem! if you are insistent on making it return nil as a design principle, you can always do it also by making your function return an optional array instead of an array: func rangeOfSearchText(searchString: String, UIText: String) -> [NSRange]? { ....

Comment: @KDiaz collection has a property called `isEmpty` exactly for this purpose. Don't use `count`. Check is your collection it is NOT empty `if !test.isEmpty {`. **When you need to check whether your collection is empty, use the isEmpty property instead of checking that the count property is equal to zero.** in this case it doesn't make a difference but if it would if it were a string.

Comment: shikai - I'll give it a try in playground.  But what I have found in my testing is that the regex function "match" never returns a nil  NSTestCheckingResults.  If there is no match, NSTestCheckingResults is an initialized empty array not nil.

Comment: Leo- Thank you. I'll use  **isEmpty**